# Sql inner join is generating duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to do a query using inner join but is not working. Its showing multiple duplicate rows. The problem is I am trying to do it by using foreign key. But I can't solve it. 
Here is first table

```
document_details

id inv_no bill_desc             bill_amount
 1 201501 test bill                    1000
 2 201501 test bill2                   1110
 3 201502 C&F Association Fee            50
 4 201502 Duty/Vat& Scanning           3620
 5 201502 Agent Charges                1750
 6 201502 Noc Charges                  1775
 7 201502 CPA Charges                  3572
 8 201502 Hi-Star Charges              1800
 9 201502 Exam. Miscellanies           5500
10 201502 Import Miscellanies          5000
11 201502 Commission@0.07%             7272
```

And the second table

```
bill_details

id inv_no doc_title            doc_desc
 1 201501 test                 test details
 2 201501 test2                test2
11 201502                      
10 201502                      
 9 201502  Doc. Recvd:26.08.15 Delivery:22.09.2015
 8 201502  Consignmnt:07Plts   Printing Chemical
 7 201502  C&F$:129896.67      BD.Tk.10388594.28
 6 201502  Inv. No:330955      Date:20.07.2015
 5 201502  L/C: 100315050139   Date:07.07.2015
 4 201502  BL No:WPG0026958    Date:01.08.2015
 3:201502  B/E No:C-992168     Date:17.09.2015
```

I am trying to run the following sql

```
$doc_query="SELECT document_details.*,bill_details.* FROM document_details
            INNER JOIN bill_details ON document_details.inv_no = bill_details.inv_no 
            where document_details.inv_no='$inv_id'";           

$get_details=mysql_query($doc_query);

while($details_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_details))
{}
```

And I am getting the following output
[image]

But I don't want this output. I am not understanding how solve show it like the following output
[image]

Comment: That's some lame advice that won't help @ReneKorss . You are joining a many to many table it's pretty obvious why it's returning multiple results.

Comment: I didn't find any duplicate row in your output.

Comment: So what's the expected result? What do you want to be returned? (Also, foreign keys are unimportant when it comes to SELECT, they are there just to make sure inserted/updated data makes sense.)

Comment: Yes you are right. I am joining many to many table. but is there any way? @Daan

Comment: You have to decide (and explain) which result you want!

Comment: @Forhad can you write your expected output so that others can think of a solution

Comment: Please give an example **of your required output** eg are you tring to output a `Total Bill Value` in the `TAKA` column?

Comment: what i can guess you want one to one join so probably used both id and invoice in your join like this SELECT document_details.*,bill_details.* FROM document_details
            INNER JOIN bill_details ON document_details.inv_no = bill_details.inv_no 
   and document_details.id = bill_details.id
            where document_details.inv_no='$inv_id'

Comment: @anwaar_hell no, nothing tells us that both ids are related.

Comment: @X.L.Ant you r right..probably we need expected output to give it a hit..

Comment: Forhad. If you dont update your question with a description of the output you are trying to achieve, I for one am going to vote to close this question as _Unclear what you are asking_ and move on to other things!

Comment: The more I look at this the more I think you either **dont understand your own data**, or **your database design is messed up**, and probably **both**

Comment: Now that you show your desired output, why do you show 'test details' with 'test bills' and 'test2' with 'test bill2'? Why not vice versa? What relates exactly the records shown? It actually seems to me, you want to show two results next to each other: the documents and the bills. And there is no real relation between a certain document and an certain bill apart from that they both belong to the same invoice number. So why not have two separate queries and use a GUI to show them in a manner you want them shown?

Comment: Yes It can be done by this. So, I can't use sql join for this. right? @ThorstenKettner

Comment: What is the relationship between `document_details` and `bill_details` **exactly** Because its not clear in any way why you want the output you ask for from the data you are processing.

Comment: Well, a join usually combines data that belongs together. 'test details' nd 'test bill' don't belong *more* together than 'test details' with 'test bill2'. This is why your join shows both combinations. If you want to show your records in a newspaper style (document details left bill details right) then have your GUI layer (e.g. a Java or C# program or PHP) care about this. You'd either use two queries or your join query to get the data; it wouldn't matter much.

Comment: You *can* achive the desired output with SQL by creating row numbers per invoice and join an invoice's bill #1 with doc #1, bill#2 with doc #2 etc. You'd use a full outer join, as you can have more bills than docs or vice versa. This is not a very complicated query usually, but it is in MySQL for the lack of row_number() and full outer joins.

Comment: yes I got it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is usually not a task for the DBMS, but for the presentation layer, i.e. a GUI program written in a programming language and showing data in grids for instance.

It can be done with SQL by creating row numbers per invoice and joining an invoice's bill #1 with doc #1, bill#2 with doc #2 etc.

So

```
id inv_no bill_desc             bill_amount  row_number
 1 201501 test bill                    1000  #1
 2 201501 test bill2                   1110  #2
 3 201502 C&F Association Fee            50  #1
```

and

```
id inv_no doc_title  doc_desc      row_number
 1 201501 test       test Details  #1
 2 201501 test2      test2         #2
11 201502                          #1
```

would give you

```
inv_no bill_desc             bill_amount  doc_title  doc_desc    
201501 test bill                    1000  test       test Details
201501 test bill2                   1110  test2      test2       
201502 C&F Association Fee            50
```

You'd use a full outer join, as you can have more bills than docs or vice versa. This is not a very complicated query usually, but it is in MySQL for the lack of row_number() and full outer joins.

So what about a simpler query giving you just one line per inv_no:

```
inv_no  bill_descs             bill_amount  doc_titles  doc_descs
201501  test bill,test bill2   2110         test,test2  test Details,test2
...
```

You achieve this by aggregating data per inv_no:

```
select 
  bill.inv_no, bill.bill_descs, bill.bill_amount, doc.doc_titles, doc.doc_descs
from 
(
  select 
    inv_no, 
    group_concat(bill_desc) as bill_descs,
    sum(bill_amount) as bill_amount
  from bill_details 
  group by inv_no
) bill
join
(
  select 
    inv_no, 
    group_concat(doc_title) as doc_titles,
    group_concat(doc_desc) as doc_descs
  from invoicedocument_details
  group by inv_no
) doc on doc.inv_no = bill.inv_no;
```